# formal definition of operations in the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, integers, natural-numbers

How do I compute step by step this formal definition of the multiplication operation $\cdot_{\mathbb Z}$ in $\mathbb Z$

$$(m,n)\cdot_{\mathbb Z}(p,q)=(m\cdot p+n\cdot q,m\cdot q+n\cdot p) ?$$

What is in fact $(m,n)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ i.e. when $(m,n)\sim(m',n')$?

Comment: Yes it works, I was just curious how to log out without your help link?

Comment: Even after clicking on log out I and closing Firefox, I can return back to my math stackexchange account in new Firefox run!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  definition of multiplication in $\bf Z$, seen as $\mathbf N\times\mathbf N$ is the following:
$$(m,n)(p,q)=(mp+nq,mq+np)$$
Just remember that $(m,n)$ is implicitly $m-n$ – except that in $\mathbf N$, this difference is defined only if $m\ge n$.